# How cache entry's valid period is calculated in MULE4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

If I cache a payload, how long it will be valid?

There are 2 settings in caching-strategy;

- Entry TTL and
- Expiration Interval.
  If I want to invalidate my cached value after 8 hours, How I should set above parameters?

What is the usage for '**invalidate cache'** processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entry TTL is how long an entry should live in the cache. Expiration interval is how frequently the object store will check the entries to see if one entry should be deleted. In your case entryTTL should 8 hours. Be mindful of the units used for each attribute. Expiration interval is a bit more tricky. You may want to check entries much more frequently to avoid them living more than 8 hours before expiring. It may be 10 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour or whatever works for you.

I explained it more in my blog: https://medium.com/@adobni/configuring-an-object-store-in-mule-4-5da609e3456a

Comment: What is the usage of invalidatecache, if we use entry ttl and expiration interval correctly?

Comment: Sometimes you may want to invalidate manually the cache instead of waiting for the automatic expiration.